# Replace Nested AsyncTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nested

In my Android application I have several Activities that all connect to one service. This service establishes a connection to a server and handles the sending and retrieving of data (xml files in most cases). Inside of my Activities I call the service functions inside of AsyncTask, because I need to do following actions based on the answer of the server. Here is an example of the structure:

```
String xmlString = "<myXmlString><myDataObject></myDataObject></myXmlString>";

final AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> myTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        showProgressDialog("Send Data...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int rc = mService.callMethod("MYFUNCTION", xmlString);
        if (rc == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        hideProgressDialog();

        if (success) {
            // handle received data
            // here it also might occur that another AsyncTask is called
            // e.g.: final AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> nestedTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() { ... }
        } else {
            // handle error
        }
    }
};

myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable taskCanceler = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (myTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
            myTask.cancel(true);

            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(taskCanceler, 15000);
```

Since I updated Android Studio it says that "This AsyncTask should be static or leaks might occur". Furthermore the nested AsyncTasks can be quite confusing sometimes, but they depend on each other so I don't really know how to change those tasks to static classes. Should I use a different approach for my needs or can I transform them into static classes and still keep the nested logic alive?

I hope I could make my issues clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asyntasks were introduced as a background method of synchronization with the ability to post results to main thread when they finish. However, they have big limitations when the logic is complicated.

They are hard to cancel properly, if they are not used correctly they can leak memory and they are cumbersome to use when there are several operations to run.

Finally, they have a hard limit on the number of them that you can execute at the same time.

[Here,](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/9) you will find a list of libraries that you can use as a replacement of Asynctask

If you are a more experienced programmer then I suggest you go one step ahead and use one of the following technologies:

[RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava): This has mainstream in android development for the last couple of years. It will help you to handle business logic, and API calls in a reactive way. The learning curve is quite steep at the beginning but later will make your life easier.
Here's an intro [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html)

**Kotlin Coroutines**: If you're into kotlin coroutines present an easy way to handle concurrency. Here you can find some [tutorials](https://www.kotlindevelopment.com/deep-dive-coroutines/)

Comment: These seems like a good place to start. I think I will take a closer look at RxJava, because AsyncTask sometimes seems to cause the problems that you mentioned. Thank you for the useful information!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are willing to change your web service access logic.

You should read about Rxjava/RxKotlin and make a quick refactoring with those technologies. 
At first it can seem complicated, but believe me, once Rx you never go back.

[See more here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a closer look at it.

Answer (score 1):

```
   private static class TASK_NAME extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            showProgressDialog("Send Data...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int rc = mService.callMethod("MYFUNCTION", xmlString);
            if (rc == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
            hideProgressDialog();

            if (success) {
                // handle received data
                // here it also might occur that another AsyncTask is called
                // e.g.: final AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> nestedTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() { ... }
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
        }
    };
```

Then OnCreateView call it like this:

```
new TASK_NAME().execute();
```

Comment: I think this will not work for me, because I can not access any non-static members inside a static class. But since I have nested tasks and need do perfom some logical things this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: of course,you need to make the variables static,just follow the android studio suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with the AsyncTasks if you understand basic threads that's enough to get done. AsyncTasks are helpers and they don't help that much. Add something like the following to your service. You generally pass a shared interface (a lambda would do great here, but alas Java7) that will trigger on the response. Then the service does the threading for you. After all it's something that will always happen given the service talks to the server. It always needs to do that in a thread anyway.

```
    HttpFetch.get(url, new UIResponse() {
        @Override
        public void response(String header, String content) {
        }
    },this);
```

Since it uses a static class for the Http work there's no leak, and you can just call it and get the response data you want. And since it's the same static class you can obviously just nest them to your hearts delight. So you send it a request and a class for the response and implement the response class.

For example here's the rest of that from when I did that very thing:

```
public static void get(final URL urir, final Response response, final Activity activity) {
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urir.openConnection();
                InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                final String content = convertStreamToString(stream);
                final String header = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
                stream.close();

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        response.response(header, content);
                    }
                });
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        response.error(e);
                    }
                });
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(run);
    thread.start();
}

static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}


public interface Response {
    void response(String header, String content);
    void error(IOException exception);
}
```

Other classes like RxJava will likely be doing the same thing. Just hand it a request with a response function and do the threading in the service and you're golden.